# Multiple entries into tableView

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I have a problem with entering multiple Attributes to my tableView. It just keeps on displaying the very last attribute. Diabetes is the only one, which I can display in the tableView.
How do I edit the code, so that TableView displays all 4?

Instead of all four, that I need. I created the attributes in core data and will try to store them into SQLite. But this is not the first entity that I created. Do I need to something different, when I try to access another entity from core data?

```
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemArray2.count
    
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GPDCell", for: indexPath)
    
    let item = itemArray2[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.age
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.bmi
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.diabetes 
    
    return cell

}


@IBAction func AddPatientData(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    var textField = UITextField()
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Patient Data", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Data", style: .default) { (action) in
        
        
        
        
        let newItem = ItemPatient(context: self.context)
    

        newItem.name = textField.text!
        newItem.age = textField.text!
        newItem.bmi = textField.text!
        [enter image description here][1]newItem.diabities = [enter image description here][1]textField.text!
        
       
        
        self.itemArray2.append(newItem)
        
       
        self.saveItems()
        
    }
    
    alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
        alertTextField.placeholder = "Add Patient Name"
        print(alertTextField)
        textField = alertTextField
    }

    alert.addTextField { (ageTextField) in
        ageTextField.placeholder = "Add Patients Age"
        print(ageTextField.text)
        textField = ageTextField

    }
    alert.addTextField { (bmiTextField) in
        bmiTextField.placeholder = "Add Patients BMI"
        print(bmiTextField.text)
        textField = bmiTextField


    }

    alert.addTextField { (diaTextField) in
        diaTextField.placeholder = "Diabieties"
        print(diaTextField.text)
        textField = diaTextField

    }
   
    alert.addAction(action)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}
    
    
    func saveItems (){
        
        do{
            try context.save()
        }catch{
            print ("Error saving context \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}

    func loaditems (with request:NSFetchRequest<ItemPatient> = ItemPatient.fetchRequest() ){
        
        do{
            itemArray2 = try context.fetch(request)
        }catch{
            print("Error fetching data \(error)")
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obvious.

This code is wrong:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
cell.textLabel?.text = item.age
cell.textLabel?.text = item.bmi
cell.textLabel?.text = item.diabetes
```

... because the .text property gets reassigned, so obviously - it is going to contain last value (`cell.textLabel?.text = item.diabetes`).

You currently use `UITableViewCell`s, but you'll have to create a `Custom Cell`, and add 4 labels, and then initialize each one's text property separately.

Below is the Complete Solution:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CustomTableViewCellDemo
//
//  Created by Pavel Palancica on 12/12/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 I Dev TV. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

struct PatientData {
    var name: String
    var age: String
    var bmi: String
    var diabetes: String
}

class PatientDataCell: UITableViewCell {
    var nameLabel: UILabel
    var ageLabel: UILabel
    var bmiLabel: UILabel
    var diabetesLabel: UILabel

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        var labelFrame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 30)
        nameLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        labelFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: labelFrame.origin.y + 40)
        ageLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        labelFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: labelFrame.origin.y + 40)
        bmiLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        labelFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: 20, y: labelFrame.origin.y + 40)
        diabetesLabel = UILabel(frame: labelFrame)

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(ageLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(bmiLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(diabetesLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private var array: [PatientData] = [
        PatientData(name: "Pavel", age: "28", bmi: "100", diabetes: "diabetes Abc"),
        PatientData(name: "Andrei", age: "31", bmi: "101", diabetes: "diabetes Cde"),
        PatientData(name: "Adelina", age: "19", bmi: "102", diabetes: "diabetes Efg")
    ]

    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = createTableView()

    func createTableView() -> UITableView {
        let tableViewOrigin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let tableViewSize = view.bounds.size
        let tableViewFrame = CGRect(origin: tableViewOrigin, size: tableViewSize)
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: tableViewFrame, style: .plain)
        return tableView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.register(PatientDataCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PatientDataCell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource Methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // return a cell of type UITableViewCell or another subclass
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PatientDataCell", for: indexPath) as! PatientDataCell

        let item = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
        cell.ageLabel.text = item.age
        cell.bmiLabel.text = item.bmi
        cell.diabetesLabel.text = item.diabetes

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate Methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 170
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to create the custom cells in Storyboard, here is an example (but you need to adapt it to your use-case):

https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/

Note that I assumed each label is having only one line, if you want them to expand on 2-3 lines if needed, you'll have to add Auto-Layout constraints and the code becomes a bit more complex, but definitely doable.

Comment: Sorry, I am a Newbie, how do I exactly go about that?

Comment: @Jonas I've just updated the answer and posted the entire solution. Note that I did create the custom cell programmatically and everything else. array is hard code, and you should have that data coming in a slightly different format, but you should be able to easily integrate it in your code. Please check it and accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to show one of those four `itemArray2` properties in four table view cells?

You're on the right track by creating a new cell, you just need to modify the function so it knows which cell it's trying to make during this specific call.
I suggest changing the `cellForRowAt` function like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GPDCell", for: indexPath)

   let item = itemArray2[indexPath.row]

   // This switch will change the contents of the cell based on the index path
   switch indexPath.row {
   case 0:
      cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
   case 1:
      cell.textLabel?.text = item.age
   case 2:
      cell.textLabel?.text = item.bmi
   default:
      cell.textLabel?.text = item.diabetes
   }

   return cell
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but If I edit the code to your suggested one. It still leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: Can you describe what you need the code to accomplish? Are you trying to create a name cell, an age cell, a bmi cell, and a diabetes cell? Or should every cell in the table view have a name, age, bmi, and diabetes label?

Comment: @guardworkingelsepanic Looks like he want each cell to contain 4 labels. I've already answered it to him.

Comment: No, I don't want a single cell to contain all four labels. I want each label in a separate cell. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jonas Could you please describe what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to add 4 attributes into my table at the same time. Each into a different cell

Comment: If you used the code that I posted and still got `item.diabetes` in all four cells it might mean that the `indexPath.row` isn't what we're expecting since that was the default case in the switch. I would try putting a break point in this function and taking a look at what index paths are showing up.